# prawn gem: Problem with positioning the text

Tags: ruby, prawn

I'm using `prawn` gem to display a text in a pdf in **two different positions and rotations** as shown in the below image[image]

I've managed to get the first one working but I couldn't able to get the second. Below is the image of what I got now [image]

Here is the code

```
require "prawn"

Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
  text "{rquestID hashtag}", align: :left, valign: :left, rotate: -90
  text "{rquestID hashtag}", align: :right, valign: :bottom, rotate: 90
end
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code isn't producing the results you want, but you can use `text_box` to get around it, e.g.:

```
 text_box "{rquestID hashtag}", align: :right, valign: :bottom, rotate: 90,
          :width => 100, :height => 100, :at => [500, 100]
```

(You may have to play around with the numbers.)